# how to handle payment response of razor pay in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

i successfully integrated razor pay in angular 2.my code is

```
 razorPay(){
      var key_id='rzp_test_mHybvn4OUmX7Qw'
       console.log("razorPay")
    var options = {

        "key": "xxxx",

        "amount": "500", // 2000 paise = INR 20
        "name": "Merchant Name",
        "description": "Purchase Description",
        "image": "/your_logo.png",
        "handler": function (response){
             this.pay_id=(response.razorpay_payment_id);
this.orderanything(this.pay_id)
        },
        "prefill": {
            "name": "Harshil Mathur",
            "email": "harshil@razorpay.com"
        },
        "notes": {
            "address": "Hello World"
        },
        "theme": {

            "color": "#F37254"
        },
        method: {
        wallet: false
      }

    };
     var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
     rzp1.open();



    }
```

but i am getting an error. Note:i declared orderanything() function in my component

> orderanything is a not function

not only this i am not able to accessing any global variable and method in inside

> function(response)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to integrate razorpay in angular2 component as:

```
razorPayOpen(){
          let options:any = {
              'key': '',
              'amount': '',
              'name': '',
              'description': '',
              'image': '',
              'notes': {},
              'prefill': {
                  'name': '',
                  'email': '',
                  'contact': ''
              }
          };

         options.handler = ((response) => {
            this.pay_id = response.razorpay_payment_id;
            this.orderanything(this.pay_id)
         });
         let rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
         rzp1.open();
}
```

Comment: i tried above code but i am getting error  "Property 'handler' does not exist on type '{ "key": string; "amount": string; "name": string; "description": string; "image": string;"

Comment: when i write let options:any it came.Than you sir..in Razor() pay how many methods are there .like rzp1.open(),,or if any docs please proved if don't mind

Comment: in options what is tid, service .

Comment: i tested the above code and its working for me. Let me know how you imported **Razorpay** in your component and version of your angular you are using.

Comment: verstion is :angular 4.. i imported like declare razorpay:any    for me also it is working.but where did you get options {"service":} ..any docs

Comment: Please help and provide full information Ankita.. How did you integrated "razorpay.js" in your angular 2 app?? and how do you capture transaction once its done?

Comment: @idleMind I recommend you to post this as a new question, for whole integration you can visit [razorpay integration docs](https://docs.razorpay.com/v1/docs)

Comment: if the transaction is failure , the handler is not called..how do i call the handler in case of failure ?